# Request firestore data in react hook asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out how to asynchronously query firestore data in my react hook.

I have seen this [blog post](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) and think I have adapted my async call to nest it inside the useEffect, however, something is wrong.

I don't get any error messages, but I also don't get to render the data from firestore.

If I remove the async fetch statements, then I can use the data in the render method.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ImpactMetricsForm from "./Form";
import firebase, { firestore } from "../../../../firebase.js";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: '8vh',
    marginBottom: '5vh'
  },
 
}));


function useGlossaryTerms() {
    const [glossaryTerms, setGlossaryTerms] = useState([])
   
    
    
    useEffect( () => {
      async function fetchGlossaryData() {

      await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("glossary")
        .orderBy('term')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
          const glossaryTerms = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
          }))

          setGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
        });
        fetchGlossaryData();
      };
        // setRelatedGlossaryTerms(glossaryTerms)
    }, [])
    return glossaryTerms;

    



const GlossaryTerms = () => {

    const glossaryTerms = useGlossaryTerms()
        
    const classes = useStyles();

    return ( 
       
            <div className={classes.root}>
            
            {glossaryTerms.map(glossaryTerm => {
              {console.log('testing log of glossaryTerms', glossaryTerms)}
                return (
                
                  <div key={glossaryTerm.id}>
                  
                    {glossaryTerm.term}

            
        </div>   
})};
     );
}
 
export default GlossaryTerms;
```

If I remove the async /await part of this hook, then I can render data. Why can't I use the hook with async?

Comment: in the code you provided, `fetchGlossaryData();` is *inside* fetchGlossaryData, so it never gets called. If that's in the original, that's your problem.

Comment: Thank you - moving down to the next line beneath the } worked. I don't know what to put where. I watched this video and couldn't follow that approach either.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQZyWTRZ3OY